# Combine all colums with duplicated and empty data into a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

In a data frame where all colums contain either missing or the same data, how can I get a vector with all the data and nothing missing, assuming no colum has all the values.

Example data frame here as I'm struggling to describe what I mean

```
x <-data.frame(c( "r", "t", "", "y"), c("", "t", "x", "y"), c("r","","x", ""))
```

desired output would be a vector like the one given with `c("r", "t", "x", "y")`, or a column like that.

I have tried using `duplicated` and distinct but haven't managed to work it.

Comment: This gives me the values, but the order is important and it returns y before x, I'll read up on what unlist is doing to see if I can maintain the order.

Comment: `setdiff(t(x), "")` as another option

Comment: @d.b please feel free to add it to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
temp = unique(c(t(x)))
temp = temp[temp != ""]
temp
#[1] "r" "t" "x" "y"
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit more convoluted, but here it goes.

```
apply(x, 1, function(y) names(table(y)[max(table(y))]))
[1] "r" "t" "x" "y"
```